If they know Feyd-Rautha's levers, why wait for him to prevail on Arrakis to control him?
Reverend Mother Mohiam and Lady Margot Fenring are discussing the weak
points of Feyd-Rautha:

Reverend Mother Mohiam: Desire and humiliation. Those are his levers.
If Feyd-Rautha prevails on Arrakis, we shall know how to control him.

If they know Feyd-Rautha's levers, why wait for him to prevail on Arrakis to control him?

If he doesn't prevail, he's useless to their plots.

In Dune, the Bene Gesserit likely allow Feyd-Rautha to prevail on Arrakis because timing is crucial for their plans. They know his weaknesses, but they wait for him to gain power as it aligns with their long-term strategy. Manipulating events when Feyd is in a powerful position allows them to exert influence at the most impactful moment, ensuring their control aligns with their broader political and genetic objectives.
